# Paste at not correct position for ellipse

Tags: qt

I have cloning the properties of entities for copy, paste. The context menu is implemented to cut, copy, paste the things. But the ellipse is not pasted at the correct position. It is pasted at some distance.

Following is my ellipse class.

```
include "ellipse.h"

Ellipse::Ellipse(int i, QPointF point1, QPointF point2, QPointF point3)
{
    // assigns id
    id = i;

    /* set values of three points
    and calculate radii of ellipse */
    p1 = point1;
    p2 = point2;
    p3 = point3;

    d12 = qSqrt(qPow((p2.x()-p1.x()), 2) + qPow((p2.y()-p1.y()), 2));
    d13 = qSqrt(qPow((p3.x()-p1.x()), 2) + qPow((p3.y()-p1.y()), 2));

    if(d12>d13)
    {
        majRadius = d12;
        minRadius = d13;
        theta = atan2((p2.y()-p1.y()),(p2.x()-p1.x())) * (180/M_PI);
    }
    else
    {
        majRadius = d13;
        minRadius = d12;
        theta = atan2((p3.y()-p1.y()),(p3.x()-p1.x())) * (180/M_PI);
    }
}

Ellipse::Ellipse(int i, QPointF point1, qreal rad, qreal radM)
{
    // assigns id
    id = i;

    /* set values of center point
    and radii of ellipse */
    p1 = point1;
    minRadius = rad;
    majRadius = radM;
}

int Ellipse::type() const
{
    // Enable the use of qgraphicsitem_cast with ellipse item.
    return Type;
}

QRectF Ellipse::boundingRect() const
{
    // bounding rectangle for ellipse
    float topLeftX = majRadius * cos(theta);
    float topLeftY = majRadius * sin(theta);
    float bottomRightX = minRadius * cos(theta + M_PI/2);
    float bottomRightY = minRadius * sin(theta + M_PI/2);

    float halfWidth = sqrt((topLeftX * topLeftX) + (bottomRightX * bottomRightX));
    float halfHeight = sqrt((topLeftY * topLeftY) + (bottomRightY * bottomRightY));

    return QRectF(p1.x() - 1.5 * halfWidth, p1.y() - 1.5 * halfHeight,
                  3 * halfWidth, p1.y() + 3 * halfHeight);
}

void Ellipse::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
                     QWidget *widget)
{
    // draws/paints the path of ellipse
    QPen paintpen;
    paintpen.setWidth(1);
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    if (isSelected())
    {
        // sets brush for center point
        painter->setBrush(Qt::SolidPattern);
        paintpen.setColor(Qt::red);
        painter->setPen(paintpen);
        painter->drawEllipse(p1, 2, 2);
        painter->save();
        painter->translate(p1.x(), p1.y());
        painter->rotate(theta);
        painter->translate(-p1.x(), -p1.y());

        // sets pen for circumference
        paintpen.setStyle(Qt::DashLine);
        paintpen.setColor(Qt::black);
        painter->setBrush(Qt::NoBrush);
        painter->setPen(paintpen);
        painter->drawEllipse(p1, majRadius, minRadius);
        painter->restore();
    }
    else
    {
        painter->setBrush(Qt::SolidPattern);
        painter->drawEllipse(p1, 2, 2);
        painter->save();
        painter->translate(p1.x(), p1.y());
        painter->rotate(theta);
        painter->translate(-p1.x(), -p1.y());

        painter->setBrush(Qt::NoBrush);
        painter->setPen(paintpen);
        painter->drawEllipse(p1, majRadius, minRadius);
        painter->restore();
    }
}

getEntity *Ellipse::clone()
{
    Ellipse *e = new Ellipse;
    e->p1 = p1;
    e->p2 = p2;
    e->p3 = p3;
    e->majRadius = majRadius;
    e->minRadius = minRadius;
   return e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getEntity *Ellipse::clone()
{
    Ellipse *e = new Ellipse;
    e->p1.x();
    e->p1.y();
    e->p2.x();
    e->p2.y();
    e->p3.x();
    e->p3.y();
    e->majRadius = majRadius;
    e->minRadius = minRadius;
   return e;
}
```